# How to put echo inside href inside php tag?

Tags: php, html

So i have `href` iside php tags and inside `href` i want to always use `ROOT_URL`:

```
<?php

  <a href="'echo escapeHtml(ROOT_URL . '?view=products');'">Delete</a>

?>
```

But i get error message: `syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ';' or ','`

How can i still use the `href` inside `php` and still use `echo` to go to link but without issues?

Comment: Surely you need the `echo` before you start outputting the HTML, rather than part-way through it? `echo "<a href='" . escapeHtml(whatever) . "'>Delete</a>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for you here, which works best depends on your preferences, code style, etc.

First, build the HTML all in PHP:

```
<?php
echo '<a href="' . escapeHtml(ROOT_URL . '?view=products') . '">Delete</a>';
?>
```

This can be written more succinctly if this is the only thing in the PHP tag:

```
<?= '<a href="' . escapeHtml(ROOT_URL . '?view=products') . '">Delete</a>' ?>
```

Second, leave most of the HTML as HTML and only build what you need to with PHP:

```
<a href="<?= escapeHtml(ROOT_URL . '?view=products') ?>">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Third, you could use a PHP framework that would give you some functional way to do this, like `<?= $html->link('Delete', ['view' => 'products']) ?>`. :-)